# Ordered list with hidden inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, hidden-field

I have such code form in my webapp (http://jsfiddle.net/eavjd5dd/) but when I send a listed item the order is as it was at the default situation.

so my question is why does the new order of the hidden values are not taken in consideration in the server side...?
Is there another function to call to apply the ordering of the ordered list...?

Thanks for the help guys :)

```
<style>
    #sortable{
        -margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0.5;
        list-style-type:;
    }
    .ui-state-highlight{
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 2px;
        border: 1px dashed black;
        height: 20px;
    }
</style>
<script>$(function(){
$("#sortable").sortable({axis: "y", placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"});
});
<script>
    <form name="categoriesManagement" method="post" action="categoriesManagement.jsp">


            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>List of categories</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ol id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="9">

                                        blabla
                                        1

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="10">

                                        blabla
                                        2

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="11">

                                        blabla
                                        3

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="12">

                                        blabla
                                        4

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="13">

                                        blabla
                                        5

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="404">

                                        blabla
                                        6

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="14">

                                        blabla
                                        7

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="15">

                                        blabla
                                        8

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="17">

                                        blabla
                                        9

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="16">

                                        blabla
                                        10

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="19">

                                        blabla
                                        11

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="18">

                                        blabla
                                        12

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="21">

                                        blabla
                                        13

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="20">

                                        blabla
                                        14

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="23">

                                        blabla
                                        15

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="22">

                                        blabla
                                        16

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="25">

                                        blabla
                                        17

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="24">

                                        blabla
                                        18

                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="categoryOrdering" value="26">

                                        blabla
                                        19

                                </li>

                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer text-right">
                        <input type="submit" value="SAVE_CATEGORY_POSITIONING" class="showToolTipTop" title="" data-original-title="Save positioning of categories.">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: I see that you have a Java Based server, could you tell me which kind of collection do you have for the server to receive data ?

Comment: I use this Collection cLongs = new HashSet(); that I convert into an array =/ why? can this be the problem...?

Comment: Try to use An ArrayList().hashSet dos not preserve order. If you really need Hashed collection with order, you could use LinkedHashSet

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot my friend the collection was the problem. I effectively converted my array of string into an array of `long[]` and it worked well.